# What does @"String"@ syntax mean in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, syntax

Not sure what this is an cant find it on the internet

```
$myString = @"
string
"@
$myRegularString = "string"

write-output $myString.getType() # outputs System.String
write-output $myRegularString.getType() # outputs System.String
```

I encountered the latter when someone converted the text of a string to a .pbk file. They originally said there was a problem converting it to utf8 but when I imported the .pbk properties from a text using  `get-content $myString -encoding utf8` file it was fine
So whats the difference? Is one fancier?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [here-strings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/), they allow to preserve formatting, including line breaks:

```
$string = @"
this is
a test
string
"@
```

Also please be aware that when you use `Get-Content -Path test.txt` the result is an array of strings (each line is an array item). If you want to get the file content as a single string object you will need to use `Get-Content -Path test.txt -Raw`.